# How do I know whether a noun is countable or not?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I'm new learner and often confused with countable nouns.

Is there any way that I can know whether a noun is a countable noun?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any online  English to English dictionary that let you know if the words countable or uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some rules to tell whether a noun is countable or uncountable, it is not easy to differentiate because what are countable in our mother-tongue may be uncountable in English and vice versa.

But some tricks may help you

*Book is countable because you can use its plural books*

**Rice is uncountable because you can not say rices**

**Gold is uncountable because you can not say golds**

But the problem in English is:

*Headache is countable and soap is uncountable.*

*suggestion is countable but advice is uncountable*

So it is beter to buy a good grammar book which deals with different  types  of nouns  and which explains countable or uncountable nouns in  detail.

You have to read grammar regularly and systematically.

Answer (score 0):

Most dictionaries indicate whether a particular noun is count or non-count.

As a general rule we can say that count nouns denote entities that can be counted, while non-count nouns denote entities that cannot be counted.

A simple test for count nouns is the ability to combine with the cardinal numbers *one*, *two*, *three*, etc.:

"one plate" ~ "two plates" ~ "three plates"  [count]

*"one crockery" ~ *"two crockeries" ~ *"three crockeries" [non-count]

The last three are ungrammatical since "crockery" is non-count and hence cannot combine with cardinal numbers.